# Ignore script file for specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need use two different commercial javascript frameworks, but problem is their collision. Is possible ignore any file for specific 'div'?

For example:

I have script xx.js and yy.js and this code

```
<div id="A">
   <div id="B"></div>
</div>
```

Div "A" will be used by both scripts,while div "B" will be used by only yy.js not xx.js .

Comment: what do the scripts do? how do they affect the `div`s?

Comment: there are two front end frameworks, we need both, but some widgets are damaged.

Comment: Please provide more information about what frontend frameworks are being used and a more detailed explanation of the collision.